# Undefined Control Sequence in apa.bbx, works fine on Overleaf

Tags: biblatex

I wrote an article on Overleaf and it compiled fine. After downloading it and running it on TeXworks, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: This suggests that your `biblatex-apa` is too new for your `biblatex`. Update your TeX distribution thoroughly (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864). If that does not help, please share the full `.log` file of the failing run with us.

Comment: @moewe is correct, the citation visibility functionality was introduced with the latest APA style and requires the latest biblatex.

Comment: See also the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656357/35864 (which has an example document to test stuff).